# AddThis not loading when using infinite scroll and isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll, addthis

I am using infinite scroll to load more data to a web page. When the page is initially loaded, AddThis is loaded with the data no problems, but on subsequent loads via infinite scroll, AddThis doesn't render.

I have this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-<key-hidden>" async="async"></script>
```

The success part of my infinite scoll js is below. I added this line (per the addthis website),

```
addthis.toolbox('#infinite-book-container');
```

to try to reload AddThis, but it doesn't seem to work

```
                success: function( data ) {
                flag = true;
                var all_html = '';
                $('#loader').hide();
                if(data.count > 0 ){

                    $('#loader').show();

                    first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                    limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());

                    $('#first').val( first+limit );

                    $.each(data.content, function(key, value ){
                        html = '<li class="book-box-content book-data">';
                        html += value.book;
                        html += '<div class="author_name" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">&mdash;<a href="/book/authors/'+value.name_slug+'.html">'+value.name+'</a></div>';
                        html += '</li>';
                        all_html += html;
                    });
                    var $newItems = $(all_html);
                    $('#infinite-book-container').isotope('insert', $newItems);
                    addthis.toolbox('#infinite-book-container');
                }else{
                    no_data = false;
                }
            },
            error: function( data ){
                flag = true;
                $('#loader').hide();
                no_data = false;
            }
```

AddThis and infinite scroll are working when used separately, but cannot get them to work together.

Comment: Why do you need to load it with infinite-scroll each time and not just load it in the page outside your `#infinite-book-container`?

Comment: Outside #infinite-book-container is how it is loading now, but when the user scrolls down and more data is loaded the AddThis part of that data is not loading with it.

Comment: A link or jsfiddle is the only way to see what is happening with your code